# Scala: foreachPartition passing Object type instead of Iterator[Row] to method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala. I'm trying to use `foreachPartition` over a partitioned dataframe. I'm trying to call a method (`makePreviewApiCall`) inside `foreachPartition`.

Here is the signature of the method being called :

```scala
def makePreviewApiCall(
  partitioned_df:Iterator[Row],
  header_df:DataFrame, 
  sqlcontext:SQLContext): Unit = {...}
```

I'm trying to call the above method from foreachpartition as below:

```scala
partitioned_df.foreachPartition(rddpartition => makePreviewApiCall(rddpartition, header_df, sqlcontext))
```

I'm getting the build error as below:

```
found   : Object
required: Iterator[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
one error found
```

What is wrong here? `rddpartition` is of type `Iterator[Row]`. Why is it being treated as an `Object`?

Comment: This explains the issue:https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32051

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like existing two methods (Scala specific vs Java specific) conflict with Scala 2.12 whereas Scala 2.11 didn't.
You can explicitly mention the type in lambda like

```
.foreachPartition((part: Iterator[Row]) => {
```